# Error with cordova build

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to run my ionic app to my android device through "ionic run android" yesterday it worked good but to day i am getting error could someone help me

```
Error: running one or more of platforms: Error Cannot find module"cordova-lib/src/cprdpva/platform_metadata"
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Things i have tried.

> 1. Removed old app installed in my mobile
>      2 updated npm
>      3 npm cache clean

my ionic info

```
Cordova CLI: 4.2.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Not installed
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should update your cordova cli version to the latest version. I believe they are at `6.5.0` nowadays. They've moved the platforms module, and I guess ionic is referring to that.